# Redshift Queries Limited to 100 mb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am new to aws redshift
I am using redshift cluster (2 nodes ra3.xplus) and while querying few tables (using the query editor), I am getting the following error:

```
the query result is 105488469 bytes after compression which exceeds the maximum size limit (100 MB)
```

And the query stops executing.
My Idea of redshift was that it is helpful for querying a large amounts of historical data, so why is there a 100mb query limit.

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve that much data via the Query Editor?

Comment: Are there other ways to query from the cluster? Like an external SQL bench that I can connect to the cluster. I am unaware of it, could you help me out with this?

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve that much data via the Query Editor? Are you trying to export data to another system? That's a lot of output for a "query".

Answer (score 3):

According to the Amazon Redshift [query editor documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor.html) there is indeed a 100Mb limit on the amount of data you can download that way. The query editor is web based and its primary purpose is for interactive, relatively smaller queries.

Redshift certainly can handle larger result sets, and for those you'd be better using an [UNLOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) to save the data to S3. UNLOAD is designed for larger datasets and automation.